# Combine enum's in swift

Tags: ios, swift, enums, switch-statement

I have two enum's for the table. In the 1st, I list the headings for the first section, in the 2nd, I list the icons for the first section.
How can I combine them into one enum

```
enum cellSectionOne:Int, CaseIterable
{
    case cellOne
    case cellTwo

    var titleCellSectionOne:String
    {
        switch self {
        case .cellOne:
            return  "cellOne"
        case .cellTwo:
            return  "cellTwo"

        }
    }

}

enum cellIconSectionOne:Int, CaseIterable {

    case cellOneIcon
    case cellTwoIcon

    var icon: UIImage {
        switch self {
        case .cellOneIcon:
            return UIImage(named: "iconOne.png")!
        case .cellTwoIcon:
            return UIImage(named: "iconTwo.png")!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915960/swift-associated-value-or-extension-for-an-enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
enum SectionTitle {
case one(identifier : String, image : String)
case two(identifier : String, image : String)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really work. Associated values aren't constants (that's the whole point), so nothing would stop you from writing `.one(identifier: "id1", image: "img2.png")`, `.two(identifier: "id2", image: img1.png)`, or any other kind of non-sense like that

Comment: he just wants to combine them. and nothing else.

Comment: From the examples, it looks like he's trying to associate one case with a ***matching*** title/image, and a second case with a second ***matching*** title/image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this.

```
enum CellSection: Int {
    case one
    case two

    var id: String {
        return value.id
    }

    var icon: UIImage {
        return value.icon
    }

    private var value: (id: String, icon: UIImage) {
        switch self {
        case .one:
            return ("cellOne", UIImage(named: "iconOne.png")!)
        case .two:
            return ("cellTwo", UIImage(named: "iconTwo.png")!)
        }
    }
}
```